# Zip headers not found, probably not a zip file - Zip4j, java

Tags: java, file, zip, extract, zip4j

I'm trying to extract zip file (I want to read it, so I need to extract it first. Or do I?) with Zip4j and it gives me the error in title. Does anyone know what's happening?

I've been trying to fix it for past 3 hours.

Comment: Are you certain you have a zip file? How was it created and can you open it with any other zip utility?

Comment: I literally just created a new zip file with WinRAR and it gave me this error. Same with all 15 different .gz files I tried - every one of them contains only one .txt file. I have no clue why it does that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it turns out I forgot to make a dot before specifying the extension ("zip" instead of ".zip"). Stupid mistake that cost me 3 hours of time :D